# How can I show all of my contacts at once in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, contacts

When I go to "My Contacts", it only displays half of my contacts (up to the letter P).  Is there a limit to how many "My Contacts" can be displayed? I have to go to "All Contacts" to display all of my contacts.

Comment: How many contacts do you have? By default Gmail only shows 50 per page. You can change that in the "General" tab in Settings. Where are you seeing "All Contacts" though? That option was removed some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Go to *Settings* → *General* → *Maximum page size*

You can choose to have either 50 (default), 100 or 250 contacts displayed per page.